# How to convert ANSI text to Unicode?

Tags: unicode, character, font-face, rtf

I would like to convert RTF text to Unicode. In the RTF font table one can find the name of the font or font-face (eg. Arial Cyr, Courier Greek) and the charset to use with it (0-255). So how to write a function that converts a character code (0-255) with these settings to Unicode?

As I see, the post-tags like Greek, Cyr, Tur etc. affect the glyph of the displayed characters and the charset affects it too. So the function could have these input parameters:

> fontname postfix, font charset, character code

But what is next? Or am I on the wrong way?

Comment: What programming language is this for? Also, fonts are irrelevant, you just need to convert the charset to, for instance, UTF-8. - [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/)

Comment: This is a duplicate , look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192319/python-convert-rtf-file-to-unicode

Comment: I am on c++ under windows. I do not believe that fonts are irrelevant, because there is for example the Symbol, the Webding and other special fontnames, which cause problem. And the fontname postfixes are important, too, but I do not know the way, how Windows handle these postfixes.

Comment: ANSI in this context is not well-defined. Microsoft used to use this term incorrectly to refer to a particular selected code page, but the proper term is character set or (in Microsoft's parlance) code page; and there is not just one. There was a proposal to standardize Windows-1252 as an ANSI code page but it basically fizzled, and what happened was that the international standard ISO-8859 made the effort obsolete. (ISO-8859-1 is by and large compatible with the Windows code page, with minor differences.)

Answer (score 4):

RTF was invented long before Unicode.  It most certainly isn't ANSI text, RTF only uses ASCII, it uses a rather unholy mix of character sets with non-ASCII characters encoded in hex with a reference to the character set.  The mapping is also not perfect, many Unicode codepoints have no corresponding charset.

You'll spend a lifetime creating your own RTF to Unicode converter.  Take advantage of an existing solution, most any platform has one.  On Windows that would be the RichEdit control.  If you use .NET then it is especially simple, use the RichTextBox class, assign its Rtf property and read back its Text property.  Which is utf-16 encoded Unicode.

Comment: Thank you very much, Hans! I will try this, and share the results.