# read error on Python in mac

Tags: python, macos

I'm a new learner of Python and use python 2.7 in mac ox 10.8.3.

Today I met a problem that python don't get the right data when executing file reading.

my input file include two website url like this:

```
    www.google.com
    www.facebook.com
```

and python codes are below, just to print the input:

```
f = open("weblist.rtf","r")
print f.read()
f.close()
```

But after run, output is like this:

```
    {\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1187\cocoasubrtf370
    {\fonttbl\f0\fnil\fcharset134 STHeitiSC-Medium;}
    {\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;}
    \paperw11900\paperh16840\margl1440\margr1440\vieww12200\viewh12840\viewkind1
    \pard\tx566\tx1133\tx1700\tx2267\tx2834\tx3401\tx3968\tx4535\tx5102\tx5669\tx6236\tx6803\pardirnatural

   \f0\b\fs36 \cf0 www.google.com\
   www.facebook.com}
```

How to solve this problem? Anyone has suggestion?

Comment: It's not a read error. Your text file is an RTF file. That's what it looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RTF files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format) are not like simple text files (for example, windows .txt files), and there're specific headers for RTF files.

You may have a try on a [simple text file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_file) instead of other kind of text files.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I changed it to a text file and solved the problem. Great Help

Answer (score 1):

You cannot treat RTF files like normal text files and read them line-by-line.

You could look at the following link on stackoverflow which deals with converting RTF files to text files.

[Is there a Python module for converting RTF to plain text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1337446/is-there-a-python-module-for-converting-rtf-to-plain-text)