# Merge RTF files with Python

Tags: python, com, rtf

I'd like to have a Python script that will automatically combine a bunch of RTF files for me. I've come across partial solutions involving opening them as Word application objects, but I don't know how to get to the next step of combining them. I also don't really have the time or the interest to learn how to manually parse RTF formats.

I suspect the files won't use different fonts or colours or anything, but that could change, I'm not the one producing them.

Comment: This question features two packages that can be used to parse rtf: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1337446/is-there-a-python-module-for-converting-rtf-to-plain-text

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.