# How to create / edit / convert to an .rtf file with Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, rtf

For creating / editing, I have tried,

```
with open(myfile.rtf, 'a') as file:
    file.write("{\rtf1\ansi{\fonttbl\f0\fswiss Helvetica;}\f0\pard")
    file.write(my_String_here)
    file.write("\par}")
```

Unfortunately the file it creates isn't an rtf file.

I can create a simple .txt file using

```
with open(myfile.txt, 'a') as file:
    file.write(my_String_here)
```

Alternatively, Is there an easy way to convert a .txt to an .rtf?

Comment: Try an RTF package https://pypi.org/project/PyRTF3/

Comment: Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1337446/is-there-a-python-module-for-converting-rtf-to-plain-text