# Convert this file in database to text

Tags: c#, sql

```
{\rtf1\fbidis\ansi\ansicpg1256\deff0\deflang3073{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Times New Roman;}}
{\colortbl ;\red0\green0\blue0;}
\viewkind4\uc1\pard\ltrpar\cf1\ul\b\i\f0\fs29 Abdominal US  examination revealed:\par
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert an rtf string to text in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5634525/how-to-convert-an-rtf-string-to-text-in-c-sharp)

Comment: The data is text.  What do you really want.  It looks like somebody took a json string and save to a file.

Comment: @jdweng, looks like raw RTF to me.

Comment: @jdweng: That is RTF. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format#Code_syntax It looks similar, but is decades older.

Comment: Welcome, you must add details, what you tried so far, what you want to accomplish, tecnologies/languages used, etc. on your question

Comment: Could be either RTF or JSON.  Only way you know it is RTF is the folder is "\rtf1".

Comment: @jdweng I am pretty sure JSON would not write the string "Abdominal US  examination revealed:" like this. Or contain that much string formating code like "fonttbl". This is RTF. As I said, they are easy to mix up on a glance. But there is no question here.

Answer (score 1):

The string you got there, is RichText as viewed by a Word Processor like Windows Notepad.

RichText - and in particular the .rtf file format - are something very old. It was the word processor format, before .doc and office became a thing. The document distribution format before .pdf's were a thing and you wanted any form of formating (so .txt are out of question).

It is remotely human readable, but not as well as XML or JSON. It is the format used by the WindowsForms RichText box. Also the Format used by the Clipboard when you copy and paste strings. It is also a good basic interchange format. But between it being very verbose and the propietrary .doc format, it fell out of use for Documents.

You got these options:

- store/send it declared as a .rtf file. As the format is so old and so basic, you would propably have to do computer archeology to find a word processor *not* able to intepret it.
- turn this RTF into flat old Notepad level .txt format, without formating.

Comment: Wordpad, not Notepad.

Comment: @Natrium I explicitly said (Windows) Notepad, because that is the only editor without formating that I can think of under Windows. Wordpad actually already had .rtf support. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordPad

Comment: ok, my bad. I see what you did there.