# Is RTF text empty

Tags: c++, text, rtf

Is there an easy way in C++ to tell if a RTF text string has any content, aside pure formatting.

For example this text is only formatting, there is no real content here:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 MS Sans Serif;}}
```

Loading RTF text in RichTextControl is not an option, I want something that will work fast and require minimum resources.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/188545/535275

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only sure-fire way is to write your own RTF parser [[spec]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140283%28v=office.10%29.aspx), use a library like [LibRTF](http://sourceforge.net/projects/librtf/), or you might consider keeping a RichTextControl open and updating it with new RTF documents rather than destroying the object every time.

I believe RTF is not a regular language, so cannot be properly parsed by RegEx (not unlike HTML, despite millions of attempts to do so), but you do not need to write a complete RTF parser.
I'd start with a simple string parser. Try:

1. Remove content between {\ and  }
2. Remove tags. Tags begin with a backslash, \, and are followed by some text. If a backslash is followed by whitespace, it is not a tag.
3. The document should end with at least one closing curly brace, }

Any content left which isn't whitespace should be document content, though this may have some exceptions so you'll want to test on numerous samples of RTF.

Comment: Good pointer to LibRTF.  From some of the samples on http://search.cpan.org/~sburke/RTF-Writer/lib/RTF/Cookbook.pod#RTF_Document_Structure, I don't think steps 1 and 2 of your proposed parser are correct and would skip non-format content.

Comment: @holtavolt: I suspect there are many RTF samples where the simple rules listed wouldn't work. It may be a good ruleset to get the 80/20 return on time and further refine from there.

Comment: I am not entirely satisfied with this answer, but after looking further in other questions and web resources, it seems that there is just no better way to do it, so I will accept it..