# SQL Server extract text from RTF saved as Image datatype

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, casting, rtf

We are using a 3rd party application (i.e. I have no control over) that is storing RTF data as SQL Server's `Image` data type in SQL Server 2016. I am fully aware that Microsoft intends to depreciate `image` datatype, but as stated this is a 3rd party application.

My issue is I need to extract the actual RTF text data that is stored - is this even possible? I have SQL Server and/or SSIS to do this. The column in question is called `NoteText`; I have tried casting as `varbinary` then casting to `varchar` like this:

```
SELECT CAST(CAST(NoteText AS varbinary(max)) AS varchar(max)) AS test1
FROM Notes
```

which does get me on the right path as it produces:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang2057{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Tahoma;}}  \viewkind4\uc1\pard\f0\fs20 Useful Text I need\par  }
```

However, I'm just interested in the:

```
Useful Text I need
```

from the result.

Within SSIS, I did try and use the Export Column transformation that did produce a rtf file but it was just full of unreadable characters.

Thank you in advance for any advice or tips.

Comment: Not with SQL. You'll have to do this with a client application and/or script.  What you ask is a complex parsing operation. SQL, the language, is terrible at text manipulation and T-SQL doesn't even have regular expressions.

Comment: Which SQL Server version are you using? All supported versions allow you to use scripts in R, Python or Java (depends on the version). All versions in mainstream support can work with Python. SQL Server 2016 (which went out of mainstream support this year) only works with R. You can find a Python package that can extract the text. Check [Quickstart: Run simple Python scripts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/machine-learning/tutorials/quickstart-python-create-script?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: If you saved the blobs to files with `.rtf` extensions they can be opened with Wordpad on older versions of Windows, or most office programs such as Microsoft Office, LibreOffice or OpenOffice.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos it is SQL Server 2016

Comment: I wonder if it would be possible with a SSIS Script task?

Comment: SSIS script tasks can't use NuGet packages, although you can use regular expressions and .NET Framework 4 libraries. It can be painful. You *can* write regular expressions that remove specific tags and replace paragraph marks with newlines etc. It's equally possible to use any other script as an external CLI command though

Comment: You should check this [related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44580580/how-to-convert-rtf-string-to-plain-text-in-python-using-any-library). The accepted answer uses only regular expressions and contains a list of RTF tags.