# Remove NEL from Text String

Tags: python

I used the script from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188545/regular-expression-for-extracting-text-from-an-rtf-string#comment78362763_188877) that extracts text from RTF files.

When I output the result into a text file I see a lot of "NEL" when viewing it in notepad++.

How can I replace "NEL"? For "NUL" I managed to remove it using replace(u'\x00', u' ')

Comment: What is NEL? Is it just three capital letters?

Comment: It's some sort of special character or symbol. Similar on how linefeeds and carriage returns are displayed in notepad++

Comment: What's its Unicode code? How does it look like in notepad? Do you have any references to it? I have never heard of it, and Google doesn't know about it, either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NEL is [Newline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline). It should be [`U+0085`](https://unicode-table.com/en/0085/).

If your editor is showing all of your text on one line with `NEL` in the middle of text, you could `replace(u'\x85', u'\n')` (or `u'\r\n'` depending on your system).

Comment: This did the trick. I couldn't find a resource to find their corresponding codes when used in replace.