# PostgreSQL: RTF->plain text

Tags: postgresql, rtf

I have the trigger in SQL Server database which extract a plain text from rtf field and store it in other field

```
update table set plaintxt=dbo.gettextfrom_rtf(rtf_field) where id=ID;
```

I use SQLCLR function dbo.gettextfrom_rtf, it is my c# extractor.

How I can do it in PostgreSQL trigger? I.e. How to implement RTF->plain text in PostgreSQL function?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing built-in, and I can't find any existing implementations. You could:

- Use some kind of [regex-based kludge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188545/regular-expression-for-extracting-text-from-an-rtf-string), though it's not going to be perfect
- Find some simple procedural implementation and port it to PL/pgSQL (here's one in [T-SQL](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/821281/Convert-RTF-to-Plain-Text-Revised-Again))
- Write a simple wrapper for some existing RTF library in another procedural language like [PL/Perl](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plperl.html) or [PL/Python](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpython.html) (probably easiest and most reliable, but will require superuser permissions)