# Convert RTF to varchar in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, varbinary

I am trying to convert a `varbinary` to `varchar` but it is causing some unwanted characters to show up, as shown below. Could someone please let me know if there is any best way to do it.

I'm trying the following query

```
SELECT
    BLOB_CONTENTS, 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), [BLOB_CONTENTS]), 
    CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), [BLOB_CONTENTS]) 
FROM 
    [hie_temp].[V500].[CE_BLOB] 
WHERE
    EVENT_ID = '760365'
```

`varbinary` code like this :

```
0x05028A64F2A9488645100E84053281148A4324080A0412A1209E4C2791CB2208EC7A3F2090C7
```

I am getting something like this

```
Šdò©H†E„2ŠC$ ¡ žL'‘Ë"ìz? Ç…ˆÔl8Œ£hÐr-ŒDBy¨O)B„IÑH\CdòA"¤Ò£Ä²)L‚V “…‚‘<¦H©@‰$â!$‡$“é¸ù°A&ˆ Ö˜M–”DŠ‘EåBI6Ý á2ˆœ (•H¥(á„Nœ“H$ÂIR9")•ñ‘’¸€„A)J¶«|xb1ÊÅã‘Ä€ŒLéE£ XÄr
```

Comment: share the query that you have tried.

Comment: Select 
  BLOB_CONTENTS,
   CONVERT(varchar(max), [BLOB_CONTENTS]),
      CONVERT(nvarchar(max), [BLOB_CONTENTS])
  FROM [hie_temp].[V500].[CE_BLOB]
  where  EVENT_ID  = '760365'

Comment: i have the hexadecimal code starting with  0x05028 from oracle

Comment: Please tag your RDBMS

Comment: how do i do it ?

Comment: What's the content of your blob? Are you sure it could be converted to text?

Comment: Its the rtf format

Comment: If you actually had the original RTF file sitting in file explorer, and you opened that file up in notepad.... _thats what you would see_ - a bunch of weird characters. Are you expecting to see bold and underline in your varchar? That's not how it works. So far you have explained a problem that consists of Oracle, SQL Server, blobs, RTF files, varchars. This is very mixed up. You need to identify a clear issue. "causing some unwanted characters" is _not_ the definition of a problem.

Answer (score 3):

RTF is not plain text, you need to write a procedure/function to convert RTF to text, see [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/821281/Convert-RTF-to-Plain-Text-Revised-Again).

Alternatively you can do it in your programming language, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188545/regular-expression-for-extracting-text-from-an-rtf-string) for an example in C#.

Comment: Thanks a lot for those post. My issue over here is there is a blob which is already created on Oracle for RTF files. So i have extracted those blob into SQl server using SSIS as varbinary. Now i want to decode that varbinary to a text. Please note: varbinary starts wit 0x05  and it is not even digits. Please correct me if i missed anything.

Comment: you can try the 1st link (the code project one) above, you might need to convert your varbinary to nvarchar(max) first and then pass it RTF2Text function.

Comment: what is the code project one? i am sorry , i am new to this. can you be bit more clear?

Comment: i have created function and passed my varbinary to it. but i get the result like below. ȅ撊꧲虈၅萎㈅ᒁ䎊ࠤЊꄒ鸠

Comment: did you try converting your varbinary to nvarchar(max), and then passing it to RTF2Text?

Comment: i tried this   Select 
  BLOB_CONTENTS
   , [dbo].[RTF2Text](convert(nvarchar(max), BLOB_CONTENTS))
  
  FROM [hie_temp].[V500].[CE_BLOB]
  where  EVENT_ID  = '760365'  correct me if i am wrong

Comment: yes, that's what I meant... not sure! you could verify if this method works by creating a sample test.rtf and inserting it in your SQL DB... maybe some format conversion has happened to your varbinary while extracting it from Oracle and copying it into sql.

Comment: sample file did work. But the blob which i have extracted from oracle are not working. They are giving me some weird characters

Comment: Ah, you have narrowed down the problem ;-)

Comment: Is there any way that i can check what is format issue and how can i resolve it ?

Comment: I am not sure whats happening there but that's an entirely new question (you might want to ask a new question and explain the steps that you have completed)