# How do I edit RTF values in a data frame on Python?

Tags: python, dataframe, iteration, rtf

unfortunately I can't get any further with my "project" and I can't find a solution that satisfies me, so I'm turning to you now and hope that I will get a good solution to my problem from you.

I would like to code the following in my Python project.
It is about a column in a data frame that brings "RTF" values and is stored as data type "object".
Some RTF contain the actual string value, e.g. ""\viewkind4\uc1\pard\lang1031\f0\fs20 This text section, is to show us how string values are stored in the database.\par" like here and right here I want my code to iterate and at the end of the iteration return me only the "pure" string value and overwrite it in the same row/column.

So the whole thing would look like this:

Before the iteration: **"\viewkind4\uc1\pard\lang1031\f0\fs20 This text section, is to show us how string values are stored in the database.\par"**
After iteration: **this text section, is to show us how string values are stored in the database.**

You can also find the following characters that you can actually delete, like **{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 MS Sans Serif** OR **\par** OR **\tab** and so on.

The lines from the dataframe are always unknown here, because I take the data from the Oracle database. Unfortunately, the string values are already stored that way in the database. So bottom line, this is pure raw data.

I hope that someone can or will help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

---

PS.:
I am open to all possible solutions. There must be another way to display RTF attributes on Python differently.

**Additional question (Optional):**
After "cleaning up" the RTF, I want to merge (comprommise) the rows, i.e. reduce rows. Each RTF in the column is referenced with an ID (column: TEXTID).
As you can see in the attached screenshot, the first 19 lines, are a whole "text", but that was split with tabs and others. After that it starts again at the 1.
Right here, the next step would be to combine all the lines that belong together.

If I could also get a possible solution from you I would be very grateful.

---

Code Part:
This is currently my solution, with which I am not satisfied.
The iteration starts from **Durch die DataFrames iterieren**

```
# DataFrames mit numerischem Suffix erstellen (z.B. df_1, df_2 usw.)
import os
import glob

# Alle CSV-Dateien im aktuellen Verzeichnis mit "Hauptstufe_" im Namen lesen
csv_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(".", "Auftrag_*.csv"))

dfs = {}
num_df = 0
for file in csv_files:
   num_df += 1
   df_name = f"df_{num_df}"
   dfs[df_name] = pd.read_csv(file)
   locals()[df_name] = dfs[df_name]

# Anzahl der generierten DataFrames und deren Namen ausgeben
df_names = list(dfs.keys())
num_df = len(df_names)
print(f"Es wurden {num_df} DataFrames generiert.")
for name in df_names:
   print(f"DataFrame Name: {name}")

# Durch die DataFrames iterieren
for df in dfs.values():
   
   # Durch die Spalten iterieren
   for col in df.columns:
       
       # Nur die Spalten mit dem Namen "Text" verarbeiten
       if col == "Text":
           
           # Die Werte der Spalte einzeln durchgehen
           for i in range(len(df)):
               
               # Den RTF-Wert extrahieren und bereinigen
               rtf = str(df[col].iloc[i])
               if rtf.startswith("{\\rtf1\\"):
                   start = rtf.find("{", 1)
                   end = rtf.rfind("}")
                   rtf = rtf[start:end]
               
               # Alle Formatierungen entfernen und nur den Text speichern
               text_parts = rtf.split("\\")
               clean_text_parts = []
               for part in text_parts:
                   if not part.startswith(("rtf", "k", "ansi", "deff", "fonttbl", "colortbl", "stylesheet", "pn", "par")):
                       clean_text_parts.append(part.strip())
               clean_text = " ".join(clean_text_parts)
               
               # Den bereinigten Text in die Spalte schreiben
               df.at[i, col] = clean_text
                
#for name, df in dfs.items(): df.to_csv(f"{name}.csv", index=False)
```

Output PNG:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BuRhN.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read [ask] and [mcve]. Also never post a picture of data, they are very poor medium to exchange it and prevent other to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I recently needed something to convert a large number of rtf-files to plain text aswell. I used this [Regular Expression for extracting text from an RTF string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188545/regular-expression-for-extracting-text-from-an-rtf-string/188877#188877) article as base and extended it to the point, where it is working with alot of different rtf-files. It surely isn't complete, because the rtf-standard is huge.
You can use and test my code below.

```
import re
import json
import logging

logging.basicConfig(
    format="%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(threadName)s %(name)s %(message)s",
    level=logging.DEBUG,
)

specialchars: dict = {
    "par": "\n",
    "sect": "\n\n",
    "page": "\n\n",
    "line": "\n",
    "tab": "\t",
    "emdash": "\u2014",
    "endash": "\u2013",
    "emspace": "\u2003",
    "enspace": "\u2002",
    "qmspace": "\u2005",
    "bullet": "\u2022",
    "lquote": "\u2018",
    "rquote": "\u2019",
    "ldblquote": "\u201C",
    "rdblquote": "\u201D",
}

specialHexes: dict = {
    "84": "\u201E", # lower double quote left
}

pattern: re.Pattern = re.compile(
    r"\\([a-z]{1,32})(-?\d{1,10})?[ ]?|\\'([0-9a-f]{2})|\\([^a-z])|([{}])|[\r\n]|(.)",
    re.I,
)

encodings: dict = {
    0: "utf8",
    2: "symbol",
    128: "cp932",  # shift_jis
    129: "cp949",  # euc_kr
    134: "cp936",  # gb2312
    135: "cp936",  # gb2312
    136: "cp950",  # big5
    161: "cp1253",  # greece
    162: "cp1254",  # turkish
    163: "cp1254",  # turkish
    204: "cp1251",  # russian
    238: "cp1250",  # east_eu
}

with open("rtf_keywords.json", "r") as f:
    destinations: frozenset = frozenset(json.loads(f.read()))

with open("wingdings_to_utf.json", "r") as f:
    winddingsConvertTable = json.loads(f.read())


class StripRtf:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.hexValue: str = ""
        self.symbolsInWingdings: bool = False
        self.inGroup: bool = False

    def unknowCharsetUsed(self, text: str, charsetNum: int) -> bool:
        return len(re.findall(r"\\f" + str(charsetNum), text)) >= 2

    def decodeHexValue(self, hex: str, encoding: str) -> str:
        byteStr = bytes.fromhex(hex).decode(encoding).encode("utf-8")
        self.hexValue = ""
        return str(byteStr, "utf-8")

    def interpreteHexValue(self, hex: str, encoding: str) -> str:
        if (
            encoding == "cp932"
            or encoding == "cp950"
            or encoding == "cp949"
            or encoding == "cp936"
        ):
            self.hexValue += hex

            if len(self.hexValue) == 2:
                if int(self.hexValue, 16) & 128: # detect leading bit
                    return ""
            try:
                return self.decodeHexValue(self.hexValue, encoding)
            except:
                if encoding == "cp936":  # fallback for gb2312
                    try:
                        return self.decodeHexValue(self.hexValue, "gb18030")
                    except:
                        logging.warnign(
                            f"Can't decode Hex {self.hexValue} for encoding {encoding}"
                        )
        elif (
            encoding == "cp1251"
            or encoding == "cp1253"
            or encoding == "cp1254"
            or encoding == "cp1250"
        ):
            return self.decodeHexValue(hex, encoding)
        elif encoding == "symbol":
            if (
                hex.upper() in winddingsConvertTable.keys()
            ) and self.symbolsInWingdings:
                return chr(winddingsConvertTable[hex.upper()])
            else:
                return ""
        else:
            if hex in specialHexes.keys():
                c = specialHexes[hex]
            else:
                c = chr(int(hex, 16))
            return c

    def stripRtf(self, text: str) -> str:
        charsets = {}

        # try to find all charsets
        for charset in re.findall(r"f\d+[0-9a-zA-Z\\]*fcharset\d+", text):
            relevantNums = re.findall(r"f(?:charset)?\d+", charset)

            charsetNum = int(re.search(r"\d+", relevantNums[0]).group())
            encodingNum = int(re.search(r"\d+", relevantNums[1]).group())

            charsets[charsetNum] = encodingNum
        if charsets:
            defaultCharset = list(charsets.keys())[0]
        else:
            defaultCharset = 0

        stack = []
        ignorable = False  # Whether this group (and all inside it) are "ignorable".
        ucskip = 1  # Number of ASCII characters to skip after a unicode character.
        curskip = 0  # Number of ASCII characters left to skip
        out = []  # Output buffer.

        self.symbolsInWingdings = len(re.findall(r"[Ww]ingdings", text)) >= 0

        # debug for missing charsets, you can comment out the exception but it may not work probably
        for charsetNum, encodingNum in charsets.items():
            if encodingNum not in encodings.keys():
                if self.unknowCharsetUsed(text, charsetNum):
                    raise Exception(
                        f"Found unknown charset-number while parsing RTF: {encodingNum}"
                    )

        encodingChange = False
        encodingHasChanged = False
        if defaultCharset in encodings.keys():
            encoding = encodings[defaultCharset]
        else:
            encoding = encodings[0]

        for match in pattern.finditer(text):
            word, arg, hex, char, brace, tchar = match.groups()
            if brace:
                curskip = 0
                if brace == "{":
                    self.inGroup = True
                    stack.append((ucskip, ignorable))
                elif brace == "}":
                    if encodingHasChanged and self.inGroup:
                        encoding = encodingOld
                        encodingHasChanged = False
                    self.inGroup = False
                    if stack:
                        ucskip, ignorable = stack.pop()
            if char:  # \x (not a letter
                curskip = 0
                if char == "~":
                    if not ignorable:
                        out.append("\xA0")
                elif char in "{}\\":
                    if not ignorable:
                        out.append(char)
                elif char == "*":
                    ignorable = True
            if word:  # \foo
                if word == "f":
                    encodingChange = True

                curskip = 0
                if word in destinations:
                    ignorable = True
                elif ignorable:
                    pass
                elif word in specialchars:
                    out.append(specialchars[word])
                elif word == "uc":
                    ucskip = int(arg)
                elif word == "u":
                    c = int(arg)
                    if c < 0:
                        c += 0x10000
                    if 55296 <= c <= 57343:  # replace surrogates
                        out.append("?")
                    elif c > 127:
                        out.append(chr(c))
                    curskip = ucskip
            if hex:  # \'xx
                if curskip > 0:
                    curskip -= 1
                elif not ignorable:
                    out.append(self.interpreteHexValue(hex, encoding))
            if tchar:
                if curskip > 0:
                    curskip -= 1
                elif not ignorable:
                    out.append(tchar)
            if arg:
                if self.inGroup and encodingChange:
                    encodingOld = encoding
                if encodingChange:
                    encodingChange = False
                    encodingHasChanged = (
                        True  # for reverting encoding when leaving closed group
                    )

                    if int(arg) not in charsets.keys():
                        continue
                    if charsets[int(arg)] not in encodings.keys():
                        continue
                    encoding = encodings[charsets[int(arg)]]

        text = "".join(out).strip()
        # text = re.sub(r"[\n]+", r"\n", text)
        return text

    def revertHexValues(self, text: str) -> str:
        result = ""
        for char in text:
            numChar: int = ord(char)
            if numChar > 127 and numChar < 256:
                hexValue = str(hex(numChar))[2:]
                result += "\\'" + hexValue
            elif numChar >= 256:
                # "{\\rtlch\\fcs1\\f0\\fnil\\fcharset0 \\u" + str(numChar) + "\\'3f}"
                unicodeChar: str = "\\u" + str(numChar) + "\\'3f"
                result += unicodeChar
            else:
                result += char
        return result
```

For above "rtf_keywords.json":

```
[
    "aftncn",
    "aftnsep",
    "aftnsepc",
    "annotation",
    "atnauthor",
    "atndate",
    "atnicn",
    "atnid",
    "atnparent",
    "atnref",
    "atntime",
    "atrfend",
    "atrfstart",
    "author",
    "background",
    "bkmkend",
    "bkmkstart",
    "blipuid",
    "buptim",
    "category",
    "colorschememapping",
    "colortbl",
    "comment",
    "company",
    "creatim",
    "datafield",
    "datastore",
    "defchp",
    "defpap",
    "do",
    "doccomm",
    "docvar",
    "dptxbxtext",
    "ebcend",
    "ebcstart",
    "factoidname",
    "falt",
    "fchars",
    "ffdeftext",
    "ffentrymcr",
    "ffexitmcr",
    "ffformat",
    "ffhelptext",
    "ffl",
    "ffname",
    "ffstattext",
    "field",
    "file",
    "filetbl",
    "fldinst",
    "fldrslt",
    "fldtype",
    "fname",
    "fontemb",
    "fontfile",
    "fonttbl",
    "footer",
    "footerf",
    "footerl",
    "footerr",
    "footnote",
    "formfield",
    "ftncn",
    "ftnsep",
    "ftnsepc",
    "g",
    "generator",
    "gridtbl",
    "header",
    "headerf",
    "headerl",
    "headerr",
    "hl",
    "hlfr",
    "hlinkbase",
    "hlloc",
    "hlsrc",
    "hsv",
    "htmltag",
    "info",
    "keycode",
    "keywords",
    "latentstyles",
    "lchars",
    "levelnumbers",
    "leveltext",
    "lfolevel",
    "linkval",
    "list",
    "listlevel",
    "listname",
    "listoverride",
    "listoverridetable",
    "listpicture",
    "liststylename",
    "listtable",
    "listtext",
    "lsdlockedexcept",
    "macc",
    "maccPr",
    "mailmerge",
    "maln",
    "malnScr",
    "manager",
    "margPr",
    "mbar",
    "mbarPr",
    "mbaseJc",
    "mbegChr",
    "mborderBox",
    "mborderBoxPr",
    "mbox",
    "mboxPr",
    "mchr",
    "mcount",
    "mctrlPr",
    "md",
    "mdeg",
    "mdegHide",
    "mden",
    "mdiff",
    "mdPr",
    "me",
    "mendChr",
    "meqArr",
    "meqArrPr",
    "mf",
    "mfName",
    "mfPr",
    "mfunc",
    "mfuncPr",
    "mgroupChr",
    "mgroupChrPr",
    "mgrow",
    "mhideBot",
    "mhideLeft",
    "mhideRight",
    "mhideTop",
    "mhtmltag",
    "mlim",
    "mlimloc",
    "mlimlow",
    "mlimlowPr",
    "mlimupp",
    "mlimuppPr",
    "mm",
    "mmaddfieldname",
    "mmath",
    "mmathPict",
    "mmathPr",
    "mmaxdist",
    "mmc",
    "mmcJc",
    "mmconnectstr",
    "mmconnectstrdata",
    "mmcPr",
    "mmcs",
    "mmdatasource",
    "mmheadersource",
    "mmmailsubject",
    "mmodso",
    "mmodsofilter",
    "mmodsofldmpdata",
    "mmodsomappedname",
    "mmodsoname",
    "mmodsorecipdata",
    "mmodsosort",
    "mmodsosrc",
    "mmodsotable",
    "mmodsoudl",
    "mmodsoudldata",
    "mmodsouniquetag",
    "mmPr",
    "mmquery",
    "mmr",
    "mnary",
    "mnaryPr",
    "mnoBreak",
    "mnum",
    "mobjDist",
    "moMath",
    "moMathPara",
    "moMathParaPr",
    "mopEmu",
    "mphant",
    "mphantPr",
    "mplcHide",
    "mpos",
    "mr",
    "mrad",
    "mradPr",
    "mrPr",
    "msepChr",
    "mshow",
    "mshp",
    "msPre",
    "msPrePr",
    "msSub",
    "msSubPr",
    "msSubSup",
    "msSubSupPr",
    "msSup",
    "msSupPr",
    "mstrikeBLTR",
    "mstrikeH",
    "mstrikeTLBR",
    "mstrikeV",
    "msub",
    "msubHide",
    "msup",
    "msupHide",
    "mtransp",
    "mtype",
    "mvertJc",
    "mvfmf",
    "mvfml",
    "mvtof",
    "mvtol",
    "mzeroAsc",
    "mzeroDesc",
    "mzeroWid",
    "nesttableprops",
    "nextfile",
    "nonesttables",
    "objalias",
    "objclass",
    "objdata",
    "object",
    "objname",
    "objsect",
    "objtime",
    "oldcprops",
    "oldpprops",
    "oldsprops",
    "oldtprops",
    "oleclsid",
    "operator",
    "panose",
    "password",
    "passwordhash",
    "pgp",
    "pgptbl",
    "picprop",
    "pict",
    "pn",
    "pnseclvl",
    "pntext",
    "pntxta",
    "pntxtb",
    "printim",
    "private",
    "propname",
    "protend",
    "protstart",
    "protusertbl",
    "pxe",
    "result",
    "revtbl",
    "revtim",
    "rsidtbl",
    "rxe",
    "shp",
    "shpgrp",
    "shpinst",
    "shppict",
    "shprslt",
    "shptxt",
    "sn",
    "sp",
    "staticval",
    "stylesheet",
    "subject",
    "sv",
    "svb",
    "tc",
    "template",
    "themedata",
    "title",
    "txe",
    "ud",
    "upr",
    "userprops",
    "wgrffmtfilter",
    "windowcaption",
    "writereservation",
    "writereservhash",
    "xe",
    "xform",
    "xmlattrname",
    "xmlattrvalue",
    "xmlclose",
    "xmlname",
    "xmlnstbl",
    "xmlopen"
]
```

And "wingdings_to_utf.json":

```
{
    "20": 32,
    "21": 128393,
    "22": 9986,
    "23": 9985,
    "24": 128083,
    "25": 128365,
    "26": 128366,
    "27": 128367,
    "28": 128383,
    "29": 9990,
    "2A": 128386,
    "2B": 128387,
    "2C": 128234,
    "2D": 128235,
    "2E": 128236,
    "2F": 128237,
    "30": 128193,
    "31": 128194,
    "32": 128196,
    "33": 128463,
    "34": 128464,
    "35": 128452,
    "36": 8987,
    "37": 128430,
    "38": 128432,
    "39": 128434,
    "3A": 128435,
    "3B": 128436,
    "3C": 128427,
    "3D": 128428,
    "3E": 9991,
    "3F": 9997,
    "40": 128398,
    "41": 9996,
    "42": 128076,
    "43": 128077,
    "44": 128078,
    "45": 9756,
    "46": 9758,
    "47": 9757,
    "48": 9759,
    "49": 128400,
    "4A": 9786,
    "4B": 128528,
    "4C": 9785,
    "4D": 128163,
    "4E": 9760,
    "4F": 127987,
    "50": 127985,
    "51": 9992,
    "52": 9788,
    "53": 128167,
    "54": 10052,
    "55": 128326,
    "56": 10014,
    "57": 128328,
    "58": 10016,
    "59": 10017,
    "5A": 9770,
    "5B": 9775,
    "5C": 2384,
    "5D": 9784,
    "5E": 9800,
    "5F": 9801,
    "60": 9802,
    "61": 9803,
    "62": 9804,
    "63": 9805,
    "64": 9806,
    "65": 9807,
    "66": 9808,
    "67": 9809,
    "68": 9810,
    "69": 9811,
    "6A": 128624,
    "6B": 128629,
    "6C": 9679,
    "6D": 128318,
    "6E": 9632,
    "6F": 9633,
    "70": 128912,
    "71": 10065,
    "72": 10066,
    "73": 11047,
    "74": 10731,
    "75": 9670,
    "76": 10070,
    "77": 11045,
    "78": 8999,
    "79": 11193,
    "7A": 8984,
    "7B": 127989,
    "7C": 127990,
    "7D": 128630,
    "7E": 128631,
    "80": 9450,
    "81": 9312,
    "82": 9313,
    "83": 9314,
    "84": 9315,
    "85": 9316,
    "86": 9317,
    "87": 9318,
    "88": 9319,
    "89": 9320,
    "8A": 9321,
    "8B": 9471,
    "8C": 10102,
    "8D": 10103,
    "8E": 10104,
    "8F": 10105,
    "90": 10106,
    "91": 10107,
    "92": 10108,
    "93": 10109,
    "94": 10110,
    "95": 10111,
    "96": 128610,
    "97": 128608,
    "98": 128609,
    "99": 128611,
    "9A": 128606,
    "9B": 128604,
    "9C": 128605,
    "9D": 128607,
    "9E": 183,
    "9F": 8226,
    "A0": 9642,
    "A1": 9898,
    "A2": 128902,
    "A3": 128904,
    "A4": 9673,
    "A5": 9678,
    "A6": 128319,
    "A7": 9642,
    "A8": 9723,
    "A9": 128962,
    "AA": 10022,
    "AB": 9733,
    "AC": 10038,
    "AD": 10036,
    "AE": 10041,
    "AF": 10037,
    "B0": 11216,
    "B1": 8982,
    "B2": 10209,
    "B3": 8977,
    "B4": 11217,
    "B5": 10026,
    "B6": 10032,
    "B7": 128336,
    "B8": 128337,
    "B9": 128338,
    "BA": 128339,
    "BB": 128340,
    "BC": 128341,
    "BD": 128342,
    "BE": 128343,
    "BF": 128344,
    "C0": 128345,
    "C1": 128346,
    "C2": 128347,
    "C3": 11184,
    "C4": 11185,
    "C5": 11186,
    "C6": 11187,
    "C7": 11188,
    "C8": 11189,
    "C9": 11190,
    "CA": 11191,
    "CB": 128618,
    "CC": 128619,
    "CD": 128597,
    "CE": 128596,
    "CF": 128599,
    "D0": 128598,
    "D1": 128592,
    "D2": 128593,
    "D3": 128594,
    "D4": 128595,
    "D5": 9003,
    "D6": 8998,
    "D7": 11160,
    "D8": 11162,
    "D9": 11161,
    "DA": 11163,
    "DB": 11144,
    "DC": 11146,
    "DD": 11145,
    "DE": 11147,
    "DF": 129128,
    "E0": 129130,
    "E1": 129129,
    "E2": 129131,
    "E3": 129132,
    "E4": 129133,
    "E5": 129135,
    "E6": 129134,
    "E7": 129144,
    "E8": 129146,
    "E9": 129145,
    "EA": 129147,
    "EB": 129148,
    "EC": 129149,
    "ED": 129151,
    "EE": 129150,
    "EF": 8678,
    "F0": 8680,
    "F1": 8679,
    "F2": 8681,
    "F3": 11012,
    "F4": 8691,
    "F5": 11008,
    "F6": 11009,
    "F7": 11011,
    "F8": 11010,
    "F9": 129196,
    "FA": 129197,
    "FB": 128502,
    "FC": 10004,
    "FD": 128503,
    "FE": 128505,
    "FF": 8862
}
```

Your above example will give "This text section, is to show us how string values are stored in the database.", even tho it isn't a valid rtf-file.
revertHexValues converts it back to valid rtf.
To test just use:

```
sr = StripRtf()
text = sr.stripRtf("\viewkind4\uc1\pard\lang1031\f0\fs20 This text section, is to show us how string values are stored in the database.\par")
print(text)
```